# Get <img>-SRC out of <content:encoded> (xsl - RSS Viewer WP)

Tags: image, xslt, rss, cdata

I need to get the image source out of this code:

```
<content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[
        <span><img width="200" src="..."></span><br /> [some Text] ]]>
</content:encoded>
```

This is what I tried:

```
 <xsl:variable name="ImageURL" select="substring-before(substring-after(content, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;&gt;')" />
 <img alt="" src="{$ImageURL}" width="75" height="49" />
```

Unfortunately my solutions failed. I also tried some other syntax but the main part was the same. Could anybody help me please?

Thanks for all effort!

Comment: Which XSLT processor exactly do you use? If possible that problem should be approached by using an extension function to parse the contents of the `content:encoded` element as an XML fragment and then simply to use XPath on the fragment to access the `src` attribute of the `img` element in the `span` element.

Comment: Sorry, I am not the XSLT pro. So what information do you need (XSLT processor?) ? I already tried to use ":encoded" but if I use this an error comes up. How do I have to use XPath?

Comment: How do I have to use XPath in a XSL Styleshhet? I looked it up but I've got no idea how to use it properly :-/

Comment: I would like to know the name of the software you use to execute your XSLT code. Common XSLT 1.0 processors are Apache Xalan (exists in Java and C++), Saxon 6, LibXslt/XsltProc, XslCompiledTransform, MSXML, to name some. As for my suggestion, don't worry about it now, first try to find out which XSLT processor you use, then we can help further. You could run http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest.xml through your XSLT processor to output some details about it.

Comment: Good question... It´s a WebPArt, embedded in Sharepoint 2010. I think it is XslCompiledTransform. Unfortunately I cant use your test in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Sharepoint WebPart uses XslCompiledTransform and allows you to use XSLT with embedded C# or VB.NET code to implement an extension function the following should help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl mf content"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
>
  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="mf" language="C#">
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO"/>
  public XPathNavigator ParseFragment(string markupFragment)
  {
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(markupFragment))
    {
      using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, 
        new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment }))
      {
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(xr);
        return doc.CreateNavigator();
      }
    }
  }
  </msxsl:script>


  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="content:encoded">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:ParseFragment(.)/span/img"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="img">
    <img alt="" src="{@src}" width="75" height="49" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note however that applying an XML parser on the markup in the CDATA section requires it conforms to the XML syntax rules so parsing X(HT)ML stuff like

```
  <content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[
        <span><img width="200" src="foo.png"/></span><br /> [some Text] ]]>
  </content:encoded>
```

will work but parsing HTML stuff like

```
  <content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[
        <span><img width="200" src="foo.png"></span><br> [some Text] ]]>
  </content:encoded>
```

will not work. Unfortunately the .NET framework class library does not come with an HTML parsing API so if the content of the `content:encoded` element is HTML you would need to look for a third party HTML parser like HTMLAgilityPack to perform the job XPathDocument does in my sample or you are really left with XPath 1.0's poor string parsing support:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl content"
>

  <xsl:template match="content:encoded">
    <img alt="" src="{substring-before(substring-after(., 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')}" width="75" height="49"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort. An answer to my question was already given here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53956/get-img-src-out-of-contentencoded-xsl-rss-viewer-wp